# Atualizar Python no LE 4.0 (Ubuntu 10)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Olá

Estou precisando usar o SimpleHttpServer e só tem para Python 2.6.6 e acima e o LE 4.0 é Python 2.6.5.

Como ele não tem software centre (pelo menos eu não encontrei) eu tentei este código no terminal mas deu vários erros:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

Alguém saberia dizer como faço para atualizar o python mesmo que seja para 2.6.6.

Obrigado

Comment: talvez começar por actualizar o ubuntu :)

Answer (score 1):

Evidentemente Ubuntu 10 já é bem antigo e eu não tenho um disponível para testar, mas você deve sim conseguir instalar Python 2.7 lado a lado com o Python padrão do sistema. O importante é não tentar substituir o Python padrão pelo 2.7 pois o várias partes do sistema deixarão de funcionar.

Tente isso:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DB82666C
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7 python2.7-dev
```

Verifique que o Python 2.7 foi instalado e está no PATH:

```
python2.7 --version
```

Se isso imprimir a versão 2.7.x, então deu certo. Verifique também que a versão padrão do sistema continua a anterior:

```
python --version
```

Você pode agora instalar easy_install-2.7 e pip-2.7:

```
curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | sudo python2.7 -
easy_install-2.7 pip
```

Answer (score 0):

O que é "LE 4.0" ?

O nome do módulo é SimpleHTTPServer (note as maiúsculas) e ele existe sim no Python 2.6.5.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Linux Educativo 4.0

Estou usando um .sh para acessar o servidor, mas não consigo incluir o script aqui porque ultrapassa o limite de caracteres.

Comment: Bem, não sei o que você está fazendo, mas o SimpleHTTPServer está sim disponível no Python 2.6.5, só que você tem que usar o nome certo, com maiúsculas...

Answer (score 0):

Se voce trocar o Python _do_sistema_ mudando a minor-version, vocÊ basicamente vai inutlizar o seu sistema e precisar reformatar. Atualizaçoes da microversion (de 2.6.5 para 2.6.6)  deveria funcionar automaticamente com apt-get se o seu sistema aina for mantido. Note que Python 2.6 é algo realmente velho, com mais de 10 anos.

Se voce precisa manter um servidor com essa idade sem atualização, a recomendação é compilar o Python de forma independente, e usar virtualenv para qualquer projeto envolvendo Python]

Ademais `SimpleHTTPServer` está sim disponível na em qualquer versão 2.6 do Python.

Comment: Eu achei que não estivesse disponível porque quando tento acessar o SimpleHTTPServer, o terminal não mostra o processo de acesso a ele e em vez de abrir a página index ele abre a pasta no navegador.